# Is there a way to use a compiled keras model on the RPI Zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I am working on a Letter Recognition Application for a robot. I used my home PC for training the model and wanted the recognition to be on the RPI Zero W with the already trained model.

I got an HDF model. When I try to install Tensorflow on the RPI zero, it's throwing a hash error, as far as I found it this is due to TF beeing for 64bit machines. When I try to install Tensorflow Lite, the installation stocks and crashes.

For saving the model I use:

```py
classifier.save('test2.h5')
```

That are the Prediction lines:

```py
test_image = ks.preprocessing.image.load_img('image.jpg')
test_image = ks.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image)

result = classifier.predict(test_image)
```

I also tried to compile the python script via Nuitka, but as the RPI is ARM and nuitka is not offering cross-compile, this possibility felt out.

Comment: did you see this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi#build_from_source

Comment: No I just found the TF Lite Installation. I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use already available TFLite to solve your issue.

If that does not help, you can also build TFLite from source.

Please refer to below links:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi

https://medium.com/@haraldfernengel/compiling-tensorflow-lite-for-a-raspberry-pi-786b1b98e646